# Referring to the quality of doing the best in what one does

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, psychology

What is the single-word or phrase referring to the attitude or quality of someone desiring to *do the best* in whatever they set out to do (regardless of the end goal).

Example:

- The new employee John is neither competitive with others, nor worried about failing in a task; all he cares about is to do the *best* job that he can within his control, and he never feels upset. His has a ___ attitude to life and work.

Comment: *Doing the best* suggests comparison with others,  whereas *doing his best* does not. Which are you looking for?

Comment: Doing his best (without comparison with others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> His has a **conscientious**  attitude to life and work.

**conscientious** (adj.)

> Of or relating to conscience; performed according to conscience; well
> and thoroughly done; scrupulous. OED

> Someone who is conscientious is very careful to do their work
> properly. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/conscientious)

> Characterized by extreme care and great effort [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/conscientious)

---

> Conscientiousness
>
> This describes the trait whereby the individual
> perceives that they have to do everything to the **absolute best of
> their abilities**. If given a target or goal, the **conscientious**
> person will **leave no stone unturned in attending to the detail of the
> task**. [Terry Radford; *Between Our Ears*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Between_Our_Ears/Tn_Pj2sqT9AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=conscientious%20%20best%20of%20their%20ability&pg=PA110&printsec=frontcover)

> **Conscientious** men and women set a **high standard of responsibility** for themselves. They believe that they must produce to
> the **best of their abilities** in social or culturally approved ways at
> all times. The **conscientious** person **must never under perform** and
> they must never have it easy.  [Ken Chapman; *Personality Making the
> Most of It*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Personality_Making_the_Most_of_It/MvPVCeTSh8QC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=conscientious%20person%20%20best%20of%20their%20ability&pg=PA20&printsec=frontcover)

> We often think of **conscientious** people as those who meticulously
> carry out out painstaking tasks. However, in the context of grit,
> being **conscientious** means **working tirelessly in the face of
> challenges** and toward the achievement of long-term goals. [Christopher
> Neck et al.; *Management*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Management/AeMJEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=conscientious%20person%20%20is%20not%20worried%20about%20failure&pg=PT209&printsec=frontcover)

> A **conscientious** person may also understand that it's one thing to
> ask a lot of yourself, **another to expect, even insist, that you
> always meet these high goals.** [J. Oldham and L. Morris; *The
> Personality Self-Portrait*](https://www.google.com/search?q=conscientious%20person%20understand%20perfection&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvKyHtj5RfqUGMeGYfXCaCBWhzbwkg:1637718253406&ei=7ZidYYr_F8eYptQPs4-DkAk&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjKqfH176_0AhVHjIkEHbPHAJI4ChDw0wN6BAgBEFE&biw=1190&bih=506&dpr=1.25) (Snippet view)

Comment: It depends what you mean by "do your best", for me conscientious would apply to someone who tries to follow all rules, satisfy everybody's needs, and fulfil all the requirements of their job, but wouldn't apply e.g. to a musician or sportsperson who strived to be the best in the world.

Comment: A musician considered best in the world by many might attribute his or her success to  conscientious adherence to a rigorous routine of, say, practice and study. If you are conscientious about any endeavor, you have a better chance of going as far as your talent/ability will take you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most common word for this is "perfectionist". The last sentence could thus be, "His attitude toward life and work is that of a perfectionist."

Comment: Perfectionism suggests overreach.